# Downvotes on question negate 1 reputation point

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

[User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411600/bratislava-bob) asked a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446990/decoding-json-information) where he recieved 9 downvotes(No positive vote).

On his [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411600/bratislava-bob) I see:

> [image: reputation]

Is downvote now negates only 1 reputation? Or Is this an exceptional case for low reputation user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411600/bratislava-bob?tab=reputation&sort=post):

[image: reputation history]

This user has received a lot of downvotes that goes beyond the minimum reputation of 1, so the downvotes did not cause further decrease in reputation. After that he received +2 for accepting an answer.

Comment: +1 good!!! now I got it as he strike the 1 at some point. thanks

Answer (score 6):

No, that is not how that works - downvotes did not suddenly cost the target 1 rep instead of 2.

What happened is that the user's reputation is so low that the downvotes brought them to the floor (1 rep). You can't go negative, so there is no way for a person with a reputation of, say, 10, to lose 18 reputation points due to 9 downvotes.

Please read the following in full:

[How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Also, regarding:

> No user has still 3 reputations

Because they've since had an upvote (+2). The system doesn't go back and say "how many downvotes did you receive while you only had 1 reputation, ok let's keep subtracting rep even as you earn more, until you're square." The downvotes that happen while you're at 1 rep are the same as the upvotes that happen while you're at 200 for the day: they stop counting.

Are you really that concerned about whether another user should have 1 rep or 3 rep?

Comment: No user has still 3 reputations

Comment: Ah, yep. They had gotten their downvotes, then accepted an answer (giving them +2 from the point of acceptance, when they were down to 1)